# Creating a custom image with UIImage and other attributes

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cgcontext, cgcontextdrawimage

I am looking to create a custom image in `iOS`. The image would be used for sharing to social sites for example.

As an example, the user might select a photo which we have a reference to as a `UIImage`. With this image we want to create another image with the original contained within it.

The idea is to create a polaroid style image with some writing/wording at the bottom. What is the best way to achieve this?

My first thought is to create a `XIB` which controls the layout and init this off screen, use a snapshot to create the finished `UIImage` and `dealloc` the view. Or would it be better to use `CGContextDrawImage`? The worry is the layout, if we have multiple items that require a specific layout is context drawing going to be easy to accomplish

Comment: too broad and opinion based

Comment: What about the question of what options are available and benefits behind them? Wouldnt say that is opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create this image below:
[Polaroid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nb3px.png)

via the following method:

1. Setup an XIB like a polaroid:
   [image: Static]
   Mine's pretty static, but you can use the File Owner and some other magic to set your image and text easily.
2. Setup a class file with the following:

   ```
   import Foundation
   import UIKit

   class LoveIs: UIView {

   class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
       return UINib(nibName: "Polaroid", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
   }    }
   ```
3. Setup your main view controller (one 'fetching' the image) like so:

   ```
   var loveIs: UIView? = nil

   loveIs = LoveIs.instanceFromNib()

   loveIs?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
   loveIs?.layer.borderWidth = 5
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext((loveIs?.bounds.size)!)
   loveIs?.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

   let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, nil, nil)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a UIView and add UIImageView and a UILabel to it. Then take the screenshot of that view.

Solution 1:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenShotView.bounds.size)
screenShotView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
letscreenShot  = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Solution 2:

```
var screenShot:UIView = screenShotView.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(screenShotView.bounds.size, true, 0.0)
screenShot.drawViewHierarchyInRect(screenShotView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
var shotCapture :UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to take generate image within code as snapshotting screen limits you to size of the screen. Also I find it easier to manage complex operations when everything is in code.

[CGContextDrawImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextDrawImage) will help you to copy original image to a region of a new image.

Below is an example how to create image yourself which contains centered text and shapes (in this case triangle with rectangular box above with name centered).

```
// Get font from custom class and create text styles
UIFont *font = [CBFontHelper robotoMedium:32.0f];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
NSDictionary *textAttributes = @{
        NSFontAttributeName: font,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [CBColourHelper white],
};
CGSize textSize = [name sizeWithAttributes:textAttributes];
// various bits of paddings and heights neccessary to calculate total image size
float gap = 2.0f;
float textHeight = 0.3f*interfacePadding + textSize.height + 0.3f*interfacePadding;
float width = 200;
float height = textHeight + gap + 2*interfacePadding;

//create new image context
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(width,height), false, 0.0f);
// Fill rectangle to hold name
[[CBColourHelper sandstone] setFill];
UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,width,textHeight));

//Draw name over rectangle
[self drawString:name withFont:font inRect:CGRectMake(0.5f*interfacePadding, 0.3f*interfacePadding, width, height)];

// Draw triangle
[[CBColourHelper sandstone] setFill];
UIBezierPath *triangle = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[triangle moveToPoint:CGPointMake(width/2,textHeight + gap)];
[triangle addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width/2,height)];
[triangle addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width/2+5.0f*interfacePadding,textHeight + gap)];
[triangle closePath];
[triangle fill];

// Get image from context 
UIImage *markerImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```